# read text file (colon-separated words) and get a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a text file called words.txt of word & description pairs separated by a colon, example:

```
word1:description 1 bla bla bla
word2:description 2 blah blah
...
```

I want a structure like this one:

```
[('word1', 'description 1 bla'), ('word2', 'description 2 blah')]
```

if you think another structure different than a list of tuples is better just tell me...I would love the solution by using list comprenhesion but I'm stucked.

Comment: your file is quite close to YAML format. If you have control over the format then you could consider using true YAML and thus make your code simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just:

```
[line.split(':', 1) for line in open('words.txt')]
```

or

```
dict(line.split(':', 1) for line in open('words.txt'))
```

Comment: +1 with a minor nitpick: he asked for tuples, so you'd need to wrap `line.spit(':')` in a `tuple()` call.

Comment: He just wants to access the word and it's meaning. The dict solution is even better. :)

Comment: A-ha! In that case I'd do `dict(line.split(':',1) for line in open('words.txt'))` just in case. :)

Comment: Somewhere I've read "if you're not going to change the data so use a tuple, they're more efficient..." or something like that, so that's the reason why I thought about a t. but it's ok I suppose.

Comment: @dobleseis You may not see any improvement by changing a list to a tuple... But, as I said, the dict solution is better! (you're doing a sort of dictionary, aren't you? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
data = []
for line in open('file.txt'):
  data.append(tuple(line.strip().split(':')))
```

The 'tuple' is only there to change the list returned by split to a tuple.

Optionally do:

```
data = dict(data)
```

afterward to change it into a word:description dictionary, which may be a better representation of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do the following

```
text = """
          word1:description 1 bla bla bla
          word2:description 2 blah blah
       """
[tuple(x.strip().split(':', 1)) for x in text.split('\n') if ':' in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[tuple(line.partition(':')[0:3:2]) for line in open('file.txt')]
```